# Fastest way to sample real values using a proportional probability

Tags: r, algorithm, normalization, sample

Given a numeric vector with `N` real numbers, what's the fastest way to sample `k` values, such that **higher values have greater probability of being selected?**

## mathematically

```
prob(X) > prob(Y) when X > Y (Linearly)
```

This is easy with `sample()` when all entries are positive, just use the `prob` arg:

```
N = 1000
k = 600
x = runif(N, 0, 10)
results = sample(x, k, replace = TRUE, prob = x)
```

But it does'n  work in my case, because some values might be negative. I cannot drop or ignore negative values, that's the problem.

So, what's the **fastest** (code speed) way of doing this? Obviously i know how to solve this, the issue is code speed - one method should be slower than other i guess:

```
1 - Normalize the x vector (a call to `range()` would be necessary + division)

2 - Sum max(x) to x (a call to `max()` then sum)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with negative values?  If you want to just ignore them, you could use `sample(x[x>0],k,T,prob=x[x>0])`.

Comment: Or simply treat them as positive? `prob=abs(x)`? I think I don't understand this question.

Comment: given x = c(-10, 0, 10), then -10 has the lower probability and 10 has the greater probability of being selected. I'll edit to explain better.

Comment: Why the downvote? people love to downvote..why? that's annoying on SO.The question is well edited and explained, if you can't or don't want to help, then leave it alone.

Comment: a simple way of making x non-negative is to `prob=x+min(x)`,

Comment: did you mean x + max(x)?

Comment: I haven't down-voted, but imagine others are because your requirement that probabilities are proportional to values and the fact that some of the values are negative and some positive are incompatible.

Comment: Yes, that's the cause of the question and the point of SO: i have a problem (100% solvable in this case) for which i need some other eyes/advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few comments.  First, it's still not exactly clear what you want.  Obviously, you want larger numbers to be chosen with higher probability, but there are a lot of ways of doing this.  For example, either `rank(x)` or `x-min(x)` will produce a vector of non-negative weights which are monotonic in x.

Another point, you don't need to normalize the weights, because `sample` will do that for you, provided that the weights are non-negative:

```
> set.seed(1)
> sample(1:10,prob=1:10)
 [1]  9  8  6  2 10  3  1  5  7  4
> set.seed(1)
> sample(1:10,prob=(1:10)/sum(1:10))
 [1]  9  8  6  2 10  3  1  5  7  4
```

On edit:  The OP is now asking for a weighting function which is "linear" in the input vector.  Technically this is impossible, because linear functions are of the form f(X)=cX, so if a vector `x` contains both positive and negative values, then any linear function of `x` will also contain both positive and negative values, unless c=0, in which case it still does not give a valid vector of probability weights.

I think what you mean by "linear" is simply `x-min(x)`.  This is not a linear function, but an [affine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).  Moreover, even if you had specified that you wanted P(X) to vary as an affine function of X, that still would not have uniquely determined the probability weights, because there are an infinite number of possible affine functions that would yield valid weights (e.g. `x-min(x)+1`, etc.)

In any case, assuming `x-min(x)` is what you want, the question now becomes, what is the fastest way to compute `x-min(x)` in R.  And I'm pretty sure that the answer is just `x-min(x)`.

Finally, for constants anywhere near what you have in your example, there is not much point in trying to optimize the calculation of weights, because the random sampling is going to take much longer anyway.  For example:

```
> x<-rnorm(1000)
> k<-600
> p<-x-min(x)
> microbenchmark(x-min(x),sample(x,k,T,p))
Unit: microseconds
               expr   min      lq  median      uq    max neval
         x - min(x)  6.56  6.9105  7.0895  7.2515 13.629   100
 sample(x, k, T, p) 50.30 51.4360 51.7695 52.1970 66.196   100
```

Comment: @Fernando Write down in mathematical terms what you want to do and we can tell you how to do it. If you can't do that, your question is off-topic.

Comment: It's obvious that you want `P(x)>P(y)` when `x>y`, but that doesn't determine exactly what `P(x)` and `P(y)` are supposed to be.  There are a lot of ways of assigning probability weights monotonically, and you have to decide which way you want to do it.

Comment: @Fernando No, it's not done. There is an infinite number of functions that will fulfill your conditions. You need to decide on a function.

Comment: @Fernando So, does that mean `prob = x-min(x)` (maybe additionally adding a tiny minimum probability `prob = x-min(x)+mP`) is the solution you are going to accept?

Comment: @Fernando If you think this answer doesn't address the question, then you have grievously failed to write the question properly.